# Laravel 5 Passing data from Controller to View with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm having an issue passing data from controller to a view loaded via ajax. Below is my code:

JS:

```
function editass(id, name, title) {
        var modal_title = document.getElementById("modal-title");
        var modal_name = document.getElementById("modal-name");
        var modal_body = document.getElementById("modal-body");

        modal_title.innerHTML=title;
        modal_name.innerHTML=name;
        modal_body.innerHTML = '<div class = "text-info" align="center">Just a moment...</div>';
       $("#modal-body").load('/SchoolSmart/public/assessments/edit/'+id);
        //alert("modal");
    }
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/assessments/edit/{id}', 'AssessmentsController@edit');
```

Controller function

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $editassessments = Assessment::findOrFail($id);
    return view('assessments.edit')->with('$editassessments', $editassessments);
}
```

View

```
Assessment name: {!! $editassessments->name !!}
```

The error returned from the header is:
**Undefined variable: editassessments**

The view loads fine if I remove the call to variable, which is the whole essence of the page. Also, this function works fine if I the view was not loaded via AJAX.

Please, help on how I pass the variable from controller to view loaded via AJAX.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the '$':

```
 return view('assessments.edit')->with('editassessments', $editassessments);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the '$' sign. I now get this error in the header:

`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$name`

I'm certain there is a 'name' parameter in the database because the index method to display all assessments work well(without ajax)